# How can i make my ListView consume as little space as necessary in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm working on a page, which requires nested ListViews. I noticed that my layout was beeing distorted by a ListView within a StackLayout which consumed way more space than the entries would require it to.

As it turns out, even without any entries, on xamarin the ListView consumes way more space than it would possibly need.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this behavior?

WPF (which renders fine):

[image: wpf rendering]

```
    <StackPanel Background="Green">
        <Label Content="hi" Background="Aqua"></Label>
        <ListView Background="Red"></ListView>
    </StackPanel>
```

Xamarin:

[image: xamarin rendering]

```
public class CustomListView : ListView
{

    public override SizeRequest GetSizeRequest(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        var sizeRequest = base.GetSizeRequest(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
        var b = this.Behaviors;
        return sizeRequest;
    }
}

public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        MainPage = new ContentPage
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Green,
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Aqua,
                Children = {
                    new Label {
                        XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                        Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                    }, new CustomListView()
                    {
                        BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In WPF you can see the result i would expect, if the ListView is displayed within a StackLayout - so far i was unable to measure children and return the SizeRequest accordingly in order to fix this.

While some other elements implement ILayoutController - ListView does not.

Comment: Indeed switch to CollectionView if you need recycling for cells or to StackLayout if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

StackLayout in Xamarin.Forms try to Fill as much space as provided by the Parent. You can get more information about it in [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stack-layout/#Sizing).

Hence, in the Code, you can try to control the Height of the either the ListView or the StackLayout by making use of either **HorizontalOptions** or **VerticalOptions**.

```
new StackLayout
{
    Children =
    {
        new CustomListView()
        {
           BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
           VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
           HeightRequest = 100 // Can be used even in ListView
        }
    },
    HeightRequest = 100 // Can be used even in StackLayout
}
```

This is the output I get when setting *HeightRequest* either ways.
[image: Output of the above code snippet]

Comment: setting the height manually is not an option. i guess this is just a bad implementation then if it does not behave like it does in WPF then... if i would want it to fill the space i would use a grid

Comment: also if i replace the listview with a label it will not consume the remaining height in parent. so in this case it's just the listview acting up

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` can behave how you want it to. If you replace `ListView` with a `ScrollView` with `VerticalOptions="Start"`, then it'll only take up as much space as you need, and become scrollable if it needs more. You can get similar functionality as `ListView` with a `StackLayout` with `BindableLayout.ItemTemplate`.

```
<ScrollView VerticalOptions="Start">
        <StackLayout
                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding YourProperty}">
                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <!-- your elements -->
                        </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Note: Setting `VerticalOptions="Start"` explicitly might not be necessary, in some cases, the parent has already done this for you (for example, if the parent is a `Grid`)

Relevant portion [from the xamarin docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scrollview#scrollview-as-a-root-layout):

In a vertical ScrollView, avoid setting the VerticalOptions property to Start, Center, or End. Doing so tells the ScrollView to be only as tall as it needs to be, which could be zero. While Xamarin.Forms protects against this eventuality, it's best to avoid code that suggests something you don't want to happen.